# Why does updateNumericInput in r shiny fail to restrict the decimal values above the max value but restricts any integer above the max?

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating a shiny app to display a cashflow statement of real estate business, where the user can change the duration to hold the property before sale and the cashflow statement should adjust accordingly. Among the inputs is the loan duration in years, which should not exceed the holding period, but should accommodate any decimal to represent any extra months.
However, upon updating the numeric input for the loan duration, it seems that only integer values above the holding period are restricted, but decimal places above the maximum value is allowed. How can this be resolved?

If possible, I would expect that either the holding period adjusts by 1 to accommodate the decimal increase of loan duration, or the updateNumericInput() restricts even the decimal places above the max value.

Comment: Hi Darius! Welcome to StackOverflow. Is it possible for you to share an example? It's not completely necessary in this case, but it would make debugging a lot easier